# Pull href from within span tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I can't figure out how to properly pull href's from within the block below and specifically the ID's (hillge01,masonfr01).

```
<div>
  <strong>Inactive: </strong>
  <span><strong>MIL</strong></span>
  <a href="/players/h/hillge01.html">George Hill</a>,
  <a href="/players/m/masonfr01.html">Frank Mason</a>,
  <a href="/players/r/reynoca01.html">Cameron Reynolds</a>,
  <a href="/players/w/wilsodj01.html">D.J. Wilson</a>

  <span><strong>LAL</strong> </span>
  <a href="/players/a/antetko01.html">Kostas Antetokounmpo</a>,
  <a href="/players/c/cacokde01.html">Devontae Cacok</a>,
  <a href="/players/h/hortota01.html">Talen Horton-Tucker</a>,
  <a href="/players/w/waitedi01.html">Dion Waiters</a>
</div>
```

So far I've managed to pull the first href using the code below but haven't been able to come up with a way to return the rest of the href's.

```
soup = get_soup(date_team)

for strong_tag in soup.findAll('strong'):
   if 'Inactive' in strong_tag.text:
   str1 = strong_tag.next_sibling.next_sibling
   print(str1)
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about adding a few newlines to that example so we can see it all on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Solutions with SimplifiedDoc.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc
html = '''
<div>
  <strong>Inactive: </strong>
  <span><strong>MIL</strong> </span>
  <a href="/players/h/hillge01.html">George Hill</a>,
  <a href="/players/m/masonfr01.html">Frank Mason</a>, 
  <a href="/players/r/reynoca01.html">Cameron Reynolds</a>, 
  <a href="/players/w/wilsodj01.html">D.J. Wilson</a> 
  <span><strong>LAL</strong> </span>
  <a href="/players/a/antetko01.html">Kostas Antetokounmpo</a>, 
  <a href="/players/c/cacokde01.html">Devontae Cacok</a>,
  <a href="/players/h/hortota01.html">Talen Horton-Tucker</a>, 
  <a href="/players/w/waitedi01.html">Dion Waiters</a>
</div>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
strong = doc.getElementByText('Inactive',tag='strong')
next = strong.getNext('a')
print(next)
next = next.next
print(next)
```

Result:

```
{'href': '/players/h/hillge01.html', 'tag': 'a', 'html': 'George Hill'}
{'href': '/players/m/masonfr01.html', 'tag': 'a', 'html': 'Frank Mason'}
```